# how get list of Object foreign key in Spring when use ManyToMany relation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, persistence

i'm have two model class.
one of them is user and other is degree.
each user can get more than one degree.
I want to send list of degrees along with Json when I create a new user in postbody.

my user class like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "USERS")
    public class User implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        private String name = "";

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "USER_DEGREE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_FK"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DEGREE_FK")
    )
    private List<Degree> degreeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public User setDegreeList(List<Degree> degreeList) {
        this.degreeList = traitList;
        return this;
    }
    public User setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }
    public User setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

}
```

and degree class have 3 attribute id, title, point.

in my controller i want when use `@RequestBody` for get user json in body, get all user degrees.

for example my controller :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object sendTechnicalMessage(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestBody User user
            ){
        return userService.createNewUser(request,user);
    }
```

and my json body like this :

```
{
  name:"abc",
  degreeList:[1,2,4,6] // or [{id:1},{id:2},{id:4}]
}
```

how can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

2 ways:

1. You can create a DTO class with field `Set<Long>` instead `List<Degree>`, convert User object to this UserDTO object and return it.
2. You can use this User class but with a specific Serializator. For this annotate the field with `@JsonSerialize(using = SomeSerializer.class)` and implement this serializer implementing `JsonSerializer<Long>` (or `Set<Long>` - I cannot say now, this is just idea).

Note: remember, that `@ManyToMany` fields by default are lazy (and almost always must be lazy) so use `@Transactional` to get a collection without exception.